# jQuery returning value 3 times in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using jQuery to get the contents of a `<strong>` tag. A sample of the code is:

```
Trip ID: <strong name="tripID">10</strong>
...    
<script type="text/javascript">
...
var tripID = $('strong[name=tripID]').text();
alert(tripID);
</script>
```

Firefox correctly `alert()`s "10". Chrome, however, `alert()`s "101010". Has anyone come across this or does anyone have any insights?

***Edit***

Changing the `<strong name="tripID">` to a `<span class="tripID" style="font-weight:bold;">` and changing the corresponding selector in my javascript made it work as expected. I'm still interested in what caused that behavior though!

***Edit 2***

I'm going to chock this up to some other part of my code interfering (it's a highly ajax-driven pages). Switching the `<strong>` to a `<span>` with a style applied corrected the issue, so I guess it's a non-problem now.

Comment: Where is the `strong` tag? Supposed to be where the span tag is?

Comment: Mmmm, your tag is span, but you're looking for a strong?

Comment: @John: OP is not trying to single out the first tag, OP believes there is only one tag in the markup

Comment: Following your edit, what does `$('strong[name=tripID]')` returns?

Comment: @Udi as I said in the question `$('strong[name=tripID]')` returns "10" in Firefox, but "101010" in Chrome.

Comment: There is only one `<strong>` on the whole page. Hence my confusion!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine. Also as Jed asked, What's the strong tag?

http://jsfiddle.net/NiceGuy4263/MjGKL/

Answer (score 0):

`<span name="xxx">` is not standard.  Try using  `<span id="xxx">` instead.

Comment: custom attributes work fine in jquery, your answer does not address the issue

Comment: Your'e right, but working against standards is a good way to get into problems.  And it did solve your problem :-)

Comment: Address my problem? What's that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
var tripID = $('strong[name=tripID]').text();
```

or

```
var tripID = $('span[name=tripID]').text();
```

jQuery returns all the elements $('span[name=tripID]') and foreach compute the text, so if you have 3 $('span[name=tripID]') all with 10 in it, it will return 101010.

I would suggest to give a class, or, even better, an ID

```
Trip ID: <span name="tripID" id="tripID">10</span>
...    
<script type="text/javascript">
...
var tripID = $('#tripID').text();
alert(tripID);
</script>
```

Comment: Haha, your tag name is `spam`

Comment: ops :-) thanks, I keep doing that also when I am coding HTML :-)